# Problem in finding Exact location with core location in iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-location

I am using the Mapkit FrameWork for an iPhone. I have city list and its famous places, hotels and restaurants. It is finding cities and famous places on map. but not hotels and restaurants.

Here is my code:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation {
NSString *strRequest; double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;

    NSString *strAddress = [searchLocationField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Search String:%@",searchLocationField.text);

    strRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", strAddress];

    NSString *strNewResult = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strRequest] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    NSLog(@"StrRequest :- '%@'",strNewResult);

    NSArray *listItems = [strNewResult componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    if([listItems count] == 4)
    {
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    else
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                        message:@"Could Not Find Address"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        }

    center.latitude = latitude;
    center.longitude = longitude;

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, 1000, 1000);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [mapView setRegion:adjustRegion animated:YES];
    return center;
}
```

Is there any way to find an **exact** location??

Comment: did your request to the service gives response for any of the restaurants and hotels from your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to monitor the exact location changes in -didUpdateToLocation. That is constantly called updating your current location for as long as [locationManager startUpdatingForLocation] is running.

When you use the region monitoring, you are only going to get 2 events, -didEnterRegion and -didExitRegion. Depending on what you are doing, the region monitoring may not be the best tool for this application.

Comment: No this is not what I want.. I am not finding current location. I am finding the location of any hotel by searching with its name in map view